# Scrollbar in a div with rounded corners

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll, scrollbar

I have a `<div>` with rounded corners. I'm actually using it as the drop down list part of a drop down menu. Inevitably, every once in awhile it will contain lots of information so it would just have to have a scroll bar. However, when the scroll bar gets displayed, it removes the rounded corners on that side which is highly undesirable. Here's the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r7uL4m7L/).

```css
#test {
  background: red;
  max-width: 200px;
  max-height: 200px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
  Text
  <br /> Text
  <br /> Text
  <br /> Text
  <br /> Text
  <br /> Text
  <br /> Text
  <br /> Text
  <br /> Text
  <br /> Text
  <br /> Text
  <br /> Text
  <br /> Text
  <br /> Text
  <br /> Text
  <br />
</div>
```

I tried using custom solution like jQuery's mCustomScrollBar which I love but it does the exact same thing with the rounded corners. Any workarounds or tips on how to approach this problem?

Comment: You can do something like this, but it will require additional div wrapper
https://jsfiddle.net/r7uL4m7L/4/   with display table, which will wrap around `#test` div

Answer (score 1):

You can use a jQuery plugin [jScrollPane](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/), and customize the color, width etc as needed.

See the following example of OS X style scrollbar. And see [here](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/dynamic_width.html) for dynamic width.

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mor7bvLt/)**

```js
$(function() {
  $('.scroll-pretty').jScrollPane({
    verticalGutter: 2
  });
});
```

```css
.scroll-pretty {
  background: grey;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: auto;
  outline: 0;
}
.scroll-pretty .jspVerticalBar {
  background: transparent;
  width: 10px;
}
.scroll-pretty .jspTrack {
  background: transparent;
  width: 8px;
}
.scroll-pretty .jspCap {
  background: transparent;
  display: block;
  height: 2px; /*same as verticalGutter value*/
}
.scroll-pretty .jspDrag {
  background: silver;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.scroll-pretty p {
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-mousewheel/3.1.13/jquery.mousewheel.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jScrollPane/2.0.23/script/jquery.jscrollpane.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jScrollPane/2.0.23/style/jquery.jscrollpane.min.css">

<div class="scroll-pretty">
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec in ligula id sem tristique ultrices eget id neque. Duis enim turpis, tempus at accumsan vitae, lobortis id sapien. Pellentesque nec orci mi, in pharetra ligula. Nulla facilisi. Nulla facilisi.
    Mauris convallis venenatis massa, quis consectetur felis ornare quis. Sed aliquet nunc ac ante molestie ultricies. Nam pulvinar ultricies bibendum. Vivamus diam leo, faucibus et vehicula eu, molestie sit amet dui. Proin nec orci et elit semper ultrices.
    Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Sed quis urna mi, ac dignissim mauris. Quisque mollis ornare mauris, sed laoreet diam malesuada quis. Proin vel elementum ante. Donec hendrerit arcu ac odio tincidunt
    posuere. Vestibulum nec risus eu lacus semper viverra.
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: You always have to have a <p> tag inside the scrollable <div>, haven't you?

Comment: Go to that plugin page and find out, looks like yes, but not necessarily to be p tag, of course it also can be div etc.